# ng-class not evaluating after a model refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a ng-repeat with an ng-class.  the getClass(item) evaluates the item in the row against an array stored in the scope. If the item exists in the array then it is assigned a class.

I have a sort function that sorts using the service with a server call.  After a refresh the ng-class doesn't evaluate anymore

here's the repeater:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in set" ng-class="getClass(item)" ng-click="selectItem(item,$event,$index)" ng-dblclick="details(item)">
    <td ng-repeat="column in columns">{{item[column.value]}}</td>
</tr>
```

Here's the getClass:

```
getClass = function(item){
    if ($.inArray(item,scope.selectedItem)>-1){
        return 'ts-li-selected';
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

here's code from the sort function:

```
$scope.filterCriteria = {
    sortDir:'asc',
    sortedBy:'UserName'
};
$scope.fetchResult = function(){
    $scope.users = User.search({sortBy:$scope.filterCriteria.sortedBy,sortDir:$scope.filterCriteria.sortDir})
};
$scope.onSort = function(sortedBy, sortDir) {
    $scope.filterCriteria.sortDir=(sortDir)?'asc':'desc';
    $scope.filterCriteria.sortedBy=sortedBy;
    $scope.fetchResult();
};
```

basically, it defaults to sorting by UserName ascending.  when you click the sort header it calls the onSort function which changes the sort criteria and fetches new results from the service.

Comment: Is `scope.selecteditem` an array?

Comment: It is an array.  I know that it has values and maintains them after the sort through a bound value outside of the list.

Comment: Provide some code around how it is sorted. Also try $scope.$apply() after the sort\update to array

Comment: I send new get command to my service which gets a newly ordered resource object.  I tried $apply() but it errors with: an apply is already in progress.  I've tried doing this client side with a sort of the resource along with a filter on the ng-repeat, but I was hoping to be able to offload it incase of a large list

Comment: Try to use the `$timeout` object to queue the `$scope.$apply()` call.